# set text into a picture frame

Tags: android, android-layout

hello i have [this image](http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/blank-black-chalkboard.jpg), i want to write text into this blackboard; this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="@drawable/blackboard">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/voto_lavagna"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textSize="90sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my problem is that if i write many text i white into the board. Can i use simple margin? how to support different resolutions? do you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your layout as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/black_board_lay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/blackboard" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/voto_lavagna"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="90sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: sorry but where is difference between my xml and your xml?

Comment: I have put one linear layout for black board under relative layout. Under that linear layout I have placed TextView. Try it, it should work for ya.

Comment: Okay, can you provide me with the exact image you are using for blackboard? And also, which screen sizes you are targeting?

Comment: Alright, first of all, I would suggest you to take optimized image of blackboard for different sizes. The image is too large for any screens that even with wrap_content, its filling the whole screen. When you get the optimized image, you can take layout_margin for TextView and display text easily inside the black board.

Comment: what is the size for large images that suggest?

Comment: You may go through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on Android developer website.

Comment: ok but my problem is blackboard border; if i have smartphone 4 inch o 4.3 inch; i have difference size, but if i fixed distance between text and border can i write over the border with a different size?